# Update google spreadsheet every n hours

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have google sheet that i want to use every day (like a main template), where I just need to add a few values in a specific cells,

i want to be able automatically or not to set those cell values everyday (let's say at midnight) back to my default values (let's say 0 or 1).

Any clue, any help, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all I need to do was create a script for a sheet

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("B2");
    var values = range.getValues();  
    if(values > 0) {
        range.setValue(0);
    } 
}
```

And after that Click on Resources, Current project's triggers.
Add new trigger and set it like this:

[image]

I think that's it, it is tested and work. 
If something is missing please edit my answer,deleting trigger or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script triggers to run your script every nth hour.

Triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Check "Managing triggers manually" section.

You will have to create a script in google spreadsheet to change the values to a default value and setup up triggers to run that script every nth hour or so.